# Python: copying RGB images inside the function

Tags: python, image, image-processing, scikit-image

I'm new to Python. I wrote (Python 3.6.1) a simple function for images rotation using `skimage.transform` tools:

```
def rotate_20rand(X):
    X_aug = np.zeros_like(X)
    for i,img in enumerate(X):
        X_aug[i] = transform.rotate(img, angle=np.random.uniform(-20, 20))
    return X_aug
```

I pass my `np.ndarray` dataset of `(34799, 32, 32, 3)` images to it. If the images are grayscale the output of the function is correct. However, after passing RGB images `X_aug` contains all zeros.

---

I've tried the following:

- First I checked if the function `transform.rotate(...)` works after I pass RGB image to it.
- Then I thought that the problem is in: `X_aug[i] = transform.rotate(img, angle=np.random.uniform(-20, 20))` and tried different `copy` methods.

None of these helped and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works for me. It produces non-zero values in `X_aug` for any type of input array.

Try this:

```
def rotate_20rand(X):
    return np.stack((transform.rotate(img, angle=np.random.uniform(-20, 20)) for img in X))
```

Comment: Thank you, @RomanMindlin, this code works for me. However I still can't understand what's wrong with the original function. Do you use Python 3 as well?

I've tried to replace `X_aug` initialisation code with `X_aug = copy.deepcopy(X)` but after the assignment operation inside the loop all entries of `X_aug` become zeros.

Comment: I've tested your code with Python 3.5.2, numpy==1.13.1, scikit-image==0.13.1. Probably, you have issue in another part of code, most likely with variables namespaces. Please, don't forget accept answer )